# how to create 5 X 5 grid in PHP ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm doing project on Graphical based password and the case is i'm creating a 5X5 grid on webpage,and use will click on the points on grid and the points will save in database,
the concern is

1. How to create Grid .. and save the points with Ajax technology or using jquery ?

Comment: What do you mean with "grid"? Maybe you could post a draft somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A grid could be both <div>  based or using a <table>.

You can give every element class a unique ID and trigger on that.

On the top of my head, a bit like:

> <div class="button"
>   id="b1">A</div>
>
> <div class="button"
>   id="b2">B</div>
>
> <div class="button"
>   id="b3">C</div>

And in your JQuery code you'd do a

> ```
> $('.button').click(function(){
>  $.post("auth.php", { which: $(this).attr("id") });
> });
> ```

Whereby your server script (auth.php) could trip which button is pressed, and hence do authentication that way.